# Transforming random variable to have distribution of another

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

How can I transform a random variable so that it's distribution matches that of a reference variable?

I have two vectors of randomly sampled values, each from a separate distribution. I don't know which family either belongs to.

The chart below shows their respective distribution:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're asking? When you say you have a "vector of their values," do you mean that you have the probabilities of those values as well? Or do you just have a random sample from that variable?

Comment: Thanks, clarified the post. I just have a random sample from each.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any reason to believe you can do this in general. Consider results of a coin versus that of a 3-sided die, for instance; your vectors could look like $\{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0\}$ and $\{3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2\}$; there's no reasonable hope of transforming either to the other. What is the context of this problem? Why do you think it should be possible (or hope it would be possible) to do this?

Comment: @MrT Are you asking how to take the probability distributions inferred from the random samples and transform one to the other, or are you asking how to transform the actual *sequence* of observations?

Comment: @Acccumulation I want to transform the actual sequence of observations, such that the difference between their probability distributions (or ECDFs) is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you can try as a first approximation: focus on using a linear transformation, and aim for the goal of getting the two variables to have the same mean and variance. Call the two random variables $X, Y$ and their respective means / standard deviations $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ and $\sigma_X, \sigma_Y$.

We want to find coefficients $a, b$ such that $a X + b \stackrel{d}{=} Y$; consequently, we will have $\mu_X = \mu_Y$ and $\sigma_X = \sigma_Y$. The standard deviation of the variable $a X + b$ is $a \sigma_X$; since we want this to be equal to $\sigma_Y$, we set $a \sigma_X = \sigma_Y \implies a = \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$. Similarly, the mean of $a X + b$ is $a \mu_X + b$; we want this to be equal to $\mu_Y$, and we already know $a$, so we can solve for $b$.

Since you don't have access to the parameter coefficients $\mu$ or $\sigma$ for either variable, you can use their estimators $\overline x, \overline y, s_X, s_Y$ as an approximation.

Note that this transformation won't be perfect. No easy transformation will smooth out those jagged edges on the blue density to make them smoothly match the red one. But, it's a start. Does this help?

Comment: Not sure how I would do this in practice; the two random variables were drawn separately, and have different lengths.

Comment: That's not a problem though, right? All you need are the mean and standard deviation of each respective list in order to calculate what $a$ and $b$ should be to transform one to the other.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread it. Yep, that ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

You've been very contradictory as to whether you want to transform the *samples* or the *distributions*. If it's the latter, all you have to do is convert between percentiles. Given an $x$ value from one distribution, find what percentile that point is, and then find what $x$ value corresponds to the percentile for the other distribution. If we call the cumulative distribution for teal $T$, and the one for red $R$, then given a point on the teal curve, you can take $R^{-1}(T(x))$, and that will give you the corresponding $x$ value for $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Aaron for pointing me in the right direction. I used his answer as a starting point and added a few bells and whistles.

I took the ECDF of the variable I want to match to (the testing dataset in the chart below) and fit a polynomial regression with the variable as the response and ECDF value as the predictor.

Using this regression, I then predicted how the variable I want to transform (the training dataset) values should be modified, using *its* ECDF values as the input. Below are the resulting distributions.

[image]

Comment: I confess that I don't see at all how my solution led you to that, but glad that it helped!

Comment: It helped me in terms of how I was thinking about the problem. I had been looking (or hoping) for an analytical solution. Your answer helped me realize I could just solve for some characteristic of the two functions; I chose the ECDF instead of mean & variance, since it addresses other issues with matches the two, but the core of my solution is effectively the same as yours.